# Does $\mathbf x\cdot \mathbf y = 0$ imply that $\lVert x+y\rVert_1 = \lVert x\rVert_1 + \lVert y\rVert_1$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces, inner-products

If **x** and **y** are orthogonal vectors and we define $\lVert x\rVert_1 =\sum^{n}_{j=1}
|x_j|$,

is it possible to express $\lVert x+y\rVert_1$ in terms of $\lVert x\rVert_1$ and $\lVert y\rVert_1$ ?

So I get that $\lVert x+y\rVert_1 = \sum^{n}_{j=1}|x_j+ y_j|$ and by the Triangle Inequality, $|x_j + y_j| \leq |x_j| + |y_j|$ so we must have that $\sum^{n}_{j=1}|x_j+ y_j|\leq\sum^{n}_{j=1}|x_j|$ + $\sum^{n}_{j=1}|y_j|$.

My question then is does **x** $ \cdot $ **y** $ = 0$ (**x** and **y** are orthogonal) imply that $\lVert x+y\rVert_1 = \lVert x\rVert_1 + \lVert y\rVert_1$ and so the Triangle Inequality is equal, and if so why?

Comment: Try $x=(1,-1)$ and $y=(1,1)$.

Comment: I think the norm should be induced from the inner product.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\|(a,b)\|_1=|a|+|b|$, we get that
$$
\begin{align}
\|(a,b)+(c,d)\|_1
&=\|(a+c,b+d)\|_1\\
&=|a+c|+|b+d|
\end{align}
$$
However,
$$
\begin{align}
\|(a,b)\|_1+\|(c,d)\|_1
&=|a|+|b|+|c|+|d|
\end{align}
$$
Thus, $\|(-1,1)+(1,1)\|_1=2$, yet $\|(-1,1)\|_1+\|(1,1)\|_1=4$

---

What is true is that if $x\cdot y=0$ then
$$
\begin{align}
\|x+y\|_2^2
&=(x+y)\cdot(x+y)\\
&=x\cdot x+y\cdot y+2x\cdot y\\
&=\|x\|_2^2+\|y\|_2^2
\end{align}
$$

Comment: What about for the infinity norm?  I can't find a counterexample for that.

Comment: The norm you are using is the euclidean norm, the 1-norm.

Comment: @MoritzDoll: I noticed that he was dealing with the 1-norm when he commented asking about the infinity norm, so I modified my answer.

Comment: I agree with Jimm. Infinity norm could be interesting.

Comment: @Jimm: $\|(2,1)+(1,-2)\|_\infty=3$, yet $\|(2,1)\|_\infty+\|(1,-2)\|_\infty=4$

Comment: Yes of course. Always try simple counterexamples. :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $x = (1,1), y = (1,-1)$. Then $x \cdot y = 0$, but
$\|x\|_1 = \|y\|_1 = \|x+y\|_1 = 2$.